# Why SUM in HQL is returning Long instead of Double?

Tags: hibernate, hql

Pvp is decimal but is returning a Long object

```
session.createQuery("select SUM(cantidad*pvp) from LineaPedido where num_pedido IN (select num_pedido from Pedido where id_cliente like " + cliente.getId_cliente() +")").uniqueResult();
```

But if I change SUM to AVG it returns a Double object

Comment: ```Object  uniqueResult() -- 
          Convenience method to return a single instance that matches the query, or null if the query returns no results.``` Looks like it returns an Object ...

Comment: what happens, if you run this on your db? maybe there is no fractional part?

Answer (score 0):

It will return the proper type.

Please refer to https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/function/StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions.java